# Store data in an inconvenient table or create a derived table?

Tags: php, propel

I have a certain predefined database structure that I am stuck with. The question is whether this structure is OK for ORM or I whether should add a processing layer that would create a more convenient structure every time something is inserted into the original DB.

To simplify, here's what it kind of looks like.

I have a person table:

```
PersonId
Name
```

And I have a properties table:

```
PersonId
PropertyType
PropertyValue
```

So, for person John Doe...

```
(1, 'John Doe')
```

...I could have three properties:

```
(1, 'phone', '555-55-55'),
(1, 'email', 'user@company.com),
(1, 'type', 'employee')
```

By using ORM I would like to get a "person" object that would have properties "name", "phone", "email", "type".

Can Propel do that? How efficient is it? Is it a better idea to create a table with columns "phone", "email", "type" and fill it automatically as new rows are inserted into the properties table?

Comment: You could define a view.

Comment: Using MySQL I highly doubt a view will be any more efficient than a query.

Comment: The purpose of the view isn't performance, it just makes it easier to access the derived data in different queries, since you don't have to write the join every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a table with columns for all properties for performance's sake like so:

```
PersonId
Name
Phone
Email
Type
```

With data like so:

```
1
'John Doe'
'555-55-55'
'user@company.com'
'employee'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should have a look to the [ExtraProperties behavior](https://github.com/Carpe-Hora/ExtraPropertiesBehavior). It basically allows you to define a set of properties for an object and easily get/set them. Your example describes the exact use case for extra-properties: a main object (Person) with some properties (phone, email, type).